# Multiplication table using appendchild and html table

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild, createelement

Could anyone help me make a multiplication table, 0-10 in an 11x11 table?
I need to use createElement/appendchild. When I use document write, it almost look complete, just miss the placement of the blue columns/rows.

It should look something like this (Only need the numbers, no fancy outline):
[image]

This is what I've got so far:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    var tabell1 = document.createElement("table");
    tabell.appendChild(tabell1);
    //document.write("<table>");

        for(var j = 0; j<11; j++){
            var rad = document.createElement("tr");
            tabell.appendChild("tr");
            //document.write("<tr>");

            for(var k = 1; k<=11; k++){
                var kolonne = document.createElement("td");
                tabell.appendChild(kolonne);
                kolonne.innerHTML = k*(j+1);
                
                //document.write("<td>"+ k*(j+1) +"</td>");
            }
            //document.write("</tr>");
        }
        //document.write("</table>")
}
```

```html
<div id="tabell"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the table using two loops.

You iterate twice from 0 to 10 included.

Use use the value 0 to represent your top row and first column, which hold the numbers to be multiplied. Since the iterator starts at 0, the value will be 0 and you can use that to detect when to add the `header` class and set the value to your non-zero iterator, either `i` or `j`:

```js
const table = document.createElement('table');

for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
  const row = document.createElement('tr');
  for (let j = 0; j <= 10; j++){
    const col = document.createElement('td');
    let val = i * j;
    if (val === 0) {
      val = i || j;
      val = val ? val : '';
      col.classList.add('header');
    }
    col.innerHTML = val;
    row.appendChild(col);
  }
  table.appendChild(row);
}

document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  background: #ccf;
}
```

Comment: ooh, I see! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The blue border can be obtained by css. See my code. I only changed four lines of loop

```js
function createTables(maxNum,limit){
 const table = document.createElement('table');
 for(let i = 0;i<maxNum + 1;i++){
  const row = document.createElement('tr');
  for(let j = 0;j<limit + 1;j++){
   const td = document.createElement('td');
   //Below four lines are new
   if(i === 0 && j === 0) td.innerHTML = '';
   else if(i === 0) td.innerHTML = j;
   else if(j === 0) td.innerHTML = i; 
   else td.innerHTML = i*j;
   row.appendChild(td);
  }
  table.appendChild(row)
 }
 document.body.appendChild(table)
}
createTables(10,15);
```

```css
table{
 border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
 padding:20px;
 font-size:25px;
 background-color:gray;
 border:2px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:center;
  color:white;
}
tr > td:nth-child(1),tr:nth-child(1) > td{
 background:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think best to use inserRow and insertCell

Cheers!

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    var tabell1 = document.createElement("table");
    tabell.appendChild(tabell1);

    for (var j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
        var row = tabell1.insertRow(j);

        for (var k = 0; k <= 10; k++) {
            var cell = row.insertCell(k);

            if (j == 0 && k == 0) { 
            
                //if first row and first column do nothing
                
            } else if (j == 0) { 
            
                //else if first row
                cell.innerHTML = k * (j + 1);
                
            } else if (k == 0) { 
            
                //else if first column
                cell.innerHTML = j;
                
            } else { 
            
                //else multiply
                cell.innerHTML = k * (j);
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="tabell"></div>
```